# elementary C issue

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

So I wish to make it so you cannot enter a number such as 0 or 11. I am using `netbeans 8.1 (GNU cygwin)`. I have found that the while loop is not being used, and that the terminal runs a successful build regardless of the loop made to ensure out of bound numbers are not existent.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
int x;
int guess = 0;
srand(time(NULL));

x = rand() % (10) + 1;

printf("random number is %d. \n", x);

printf("whats your guess? 3 tries. between 1 and 10 \n");
scanf("%d", guess);

while (guess >10 || guess < 0){
    printf(" your guess is out of the bounds (1 to 10) re enter: \n");
    scanf("%d", guess);
}

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

Any ideas?
I intend to make several comparisons to 'x' later.

Comment: What's the value returned from the `scanf()` calls?  You're not testing for failure.

Comment: you need to put an ampersand in front of `guess` ... `scanf("%d", &guess);`

Comment: If you can't use a debugger you could at least add some print statements in there to help.  I suggest adding `fprintf(stderr, "guess = %d\n", guess);` in a few places.

Comment: I tested it by returning the value of guess in a printf. Thanks yano, just forgot &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply needs a & (ampersand) in the scan f statement.

```
   scanf("%d", &guess);
```